# How to check see if the location searched is matched in the api and show an alert to the user if it doesn't match

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, event-listener

At the minute it just shows a fault in the console if you don't search a location in the API(ie Spelling mistake etc..), how do I alert the user when this happens?

```
     const cityRef = document.querySelector('#location #city');
      
     const searchbar = document.querySelector('.search-bar');
     searchbar.addEventListener('keypress', searchQuery);
     
     function searchQuery(evt) {
      if (evt.keyCode == 13) {
        searchbar.value && getData( searchbar.value );
      }
    }

     function getData(query) {
       fetch(`${api.base}weather?q=${query}&units=metric&APPID=${api.key}`)
       .then(weather => weather.json()).then(displayData);
     };
    

     function displayData(weather) {
       cityRef.innerText = `${weather.name}, ${weather.sys.country}`;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle error inside catch error block.

Example:

```
function getData(query) {
  fetch(`${api.base}weather?q=${query}&units=metric&APPID=${api.key}`)
    .then(weather => weather.json()).then(displayData).catch(error => {
      // handle your error
      alert("Your Error Message")
    });
};
```